# Show the set is open by purely using definition of open in a metric space

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Show $S = \{(x,y)\in \mathbb R^{2}: y > x^2\}$ is open by using the definition of an open set.

Here is my attempt:

Choose a point $a \in S$, try to find a ball with radius $r$, such that $B(a,r) \subseteq S$.

Which means $\forall x \in \mathbb R ^{2}, |x - a| \lt r \implies x \in S$

My problem is I have no idea how to determine the radius $r$, can someone help me?

Thanks!

Comment: Drawing a picture would be helpful.

Comment: Notice that for any $(u,v)$ we have $v - u^2 = v - y + y - x^2 + x^2 - u^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Draw a picture. Pick a point $(x_0,y_0)$ above the graph of $y=x^2$. Find that setting 
$$
r=\frac{1}{2}\min \{ |x_0-\sqrt{y_0}|, |x_0+\sqrt{y_0}|, |y_0-x_0^2|\}
$$
does it.

Comment: Thanks! I am wondering where $|y_{0} - y_{0}^{2}|$ comes from? Should it be $|y_{0} - x_{0}^2|$?

Comment: @ZHANGYUE yes I am so sorry. well it seems you understood!